react: passed state update handler works only once
In a react app, I need to keep track of a state variable that amounts to a Map in which each key is a string and each value is a boolean, like this:
new Map([['a',true],['b',false],['c',true]])

The app should present the user with a button for each map in the key.  Clicking the button should toggle the value at that key between true and false.
I'm trying to implement this by passing a handler function down the tree that takes the name of a key as an argument and returns a function to fire on a button click.
Here is a simplified version of the code I'm using:
import { useState } from "react"

export default function Try(){
  const [selectedLetters, setSelectedLetters] = useState(new Map([['a', false],['b',false]]))
  function handleToggleLetterSelected (letter: string) {
    return(() => {
      setSelectedLetters((selectedLetters) => {
        if (selectedLetters.get(letter)) {
          return(new Map(selectedLetters.set(letter, false)))
        } else {
          return(new Map(selectedLetters.set(letter, true)))
        }
      })
    })
  }
  return(
    <div>
      {['a','b'].map((letter) => (
        <button
          key={letter}
          onClick={handleToggleLetterSelected(letter)}
        >
          {selectedLetters.get(letter) ? (<span>Unselect</span>) : (<span>Select</span>)} 
          <span>{letter}</span>
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

What I expect is that clicking each button will flip the boolean value for it's letter.
But this isn't working.
Instead, when the component renders, clicking on either button flips the value for the appropriate letter as expected.  But any further clicks have no effect on the state.
For what it's worth, I'm running this in Nextjs using the Pages router.  So if the React code above looks good, perhaps it's something I'm doing wrong with Nextjs.  My experience with Next is that it never works as I expect the first 40 times or so!

You are mutating state in your code:
return new Map(selectedLetters.set(letter, false));

Map.prototype.set updates the entry in the Map. In the above code selectedLetters.set(letter, false) is mutating the state variable. This is never a good practice in React and you can see why.
The way to go about it would be by creating a copy first and then updating:
export default function App() {
  const [selectedLetters, setSelectedLetters] = useState(
    new Map([
      ["a", false],
      ["b", false],
    ]),
  );

  function handleToggleLetterSelected(letter: string) {
    return () =>
      setSelectedLetters((prev) => {
        const newMap = new Map(prev);
        if (newMap.get(letter)) {
          newMap.set(letter, false);
          return newMap;
        } else {
          newMap.set(letter, true);
          return newMap;
        }
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {["a", "b"].map((letter) => (
        <button key={letter} onClick={handleToggleLetterSelected(letter)}>
          {selectedLetters.get(letter) ? (
            <span>Unselect</span>
          ) : (
            <span>Select</span>
          )}
          <span>{letter}</span>
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

The above would work. Here is a demo

Bonus: If you want your existing code to work as it is just switch off React.StrictMode. To do that remove the wrapping <React.StrictMode>. It would be in your index.js or main.js file wrapping your App component. StrictMode has a few quirks that help in finding exactly these kinds of issues during development. Remember, StrictMode has no effect in production builds so your above code would work as expected in production. But still, mutating the state is a problem and the React core team recommends against it. You are able to catch the issue exactly because of StrictMode.
What is happening is a double rendering caused intentionally by React during StrictMode development. Now during this second render, the state value is being picked up, which unfortunately was mutated. This causes the wrong JSX to render and hence the method to not run as expected. You can put logs to check this.
Demo without StrictMode.

Thank you!  In initially writing the handler, I got focused on the fact that Map.prototype.set() returns the newly-mutated copy.  So, I thought..."cool, I'll just do setState((old) => (old.set(key,newval))".  But of course...as you point out...that's still mutating the old state!

Yes. And as I mentioned this is only a StrictMode thing. Without StrictMode it works as expected
